# How can we use generators to write async code in a sync way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-harmony

I have read that generators, coming with ECMAScript 6 and already available in node.js dev version, will make easier to write async code in a sync way. But it was really hard to understand to me, **how can we use generators to write async code ?**

Comment: So, why are you asking, if you already know the answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to understand generators / yield in node.js - what executes the asynchronous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516952/trying-to-understand-generators-yield-in-node-js-what-executes-the-asynchron)

Comment: The question is too generic for that.

Answer (score 2):

We first have to remember that with ES generators, we can pass a value to the `next()` method, which will be the return value of the yield statement in the generator.

The idea is to give the generator to a kind of controller function.

In the generator, each time we call an async function, we `yield`, so we give back control to the controller function. The controller function does nothing but calling `next()` when the async operation is done. During this time, we can handle other events, so it's non-blocking.

**Example without generators :**

```
// chain of callbacks
function findAuthorOfArticleOfComment (commentID, callback) {
  database.comments.find( {id: commentID}
                        , function (err, comment) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    database.articles.find( { id: comment.articleID }
                          , function (err, article) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      database.users.find( { id: article.authorID }
                         , function (err, author) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(author);
      });
    });
  });
}
findAuthorOfArticleOfComment (commentID, function(err, author) {
  if(!err) console.log(author);
}
```

**Example with generators :**

We have to use a library which will control the flow, like [suspend](https://github.com/jmar777/suspend) or [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) if you want to use it with Promises. I will give an example without library for better understanding.

```
function* myGenerator(resume, commentID, callback) {
  var comment, article, author;
  comment = yield database.comments.find( {id: commentID}, resume);
  article = yield database.articles.find( {id: comment.articleID}, resume);
  author = yield database.users.find( {id: article.authorID}, resume);
};

// in real life we use a library for this !
var findAuthorOfArticleOfComment = function(commentID, callback) {
  var resume, theGenerator;
  resume = function (err, result) {
    var next;
    if(err) return callback(err);
    next = theGenerator.next(result);
    if (next.done) callback(null, result);
  }
  theGenerator = myGenerator(resume, commentID, callback);
  theGenerator.next();
}

// still the same function as first example !
findAuthorOfArticleOfComment (commentID, function(err, author) {
  if(!err) console.log(author);
}
```

What we do :

- create the generator, giving a resume function as the first parameter, an parameters given by the function caller
- call `next()` a first time. Our first async function is reached and the generator yield.
- each time the `resume` function is called, we get the value and pass it to next, so the code in the generator continue execution and the yield statement returns the correct value.

In real life we will use a library, and give the generator as parameter to a generic controller function. So all we have to write is the generator, and the `value = yield asyncFunction(parameters, resumeCallback);`, or `value = yield functionReturningPromise(parameters);` if you use Promises (with a Promise compatible library). It is really a good way to write async code in a sync looking way.

---

Excellent sources :
http://tobyho.com/2013/06/16/what-are-generators/
http://jlongster.com/A-Closer-Look-at-Generators-Without-Promises

Comment: Why would you use that `resume` callback with generators? It looks somehow ugly. Can't we `return` like in synchronous code?

Comment: This example is made the simplest as possible to understand how it works without the magic. Most of the time you will use a library like bluebird, which support Promises. In this case you will indeed yield a Promise and bluebird will call next() when promise resolve. But if you just return without using Promises, this will be sync and therefore blocking code, it would loose all the interest. Yield in itself does not add any async magic, it just stop the execution of the generator. So if you want even more "magic" and use return instead of callback, you'd better check bluebird.

Comment: I know (and I'm using Promises already), I just suggested there might be a better pattern to get the result out of the `myGenerator` (not out of the asynchronous `findAuthorOfArticleOfComment`, of course)

Comment: Non-promise generator libraries all use callbacks or wrapper functions wich handle callbacks in the end. AFAIK, Promise or callbacks are the only ways for a function to return a result asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, but only in the end, not in the generator, don't they?

Comment: Check https://github.com/jmar777/suspend which is the less magic generator library I know. They use callback in the generator. With all other libraries you have to wrap all the functions you call in the generator so they yield some kind of thenable, which is kind of the same as using self-made promises. How do you want otherwise the function you yield would return there result asynchronously ?

Comment: `run` does have a callback, and they pass `resume()` as a callback to every function they "`yield` to", but they never invoke a callback explicitly in the generator. Instead, they simply `yield` the async call, or even `return JSON.parse(rawFile)` from the generator.

Comment: Oh I understand your point! We were not talking about the same thing. Youre right it is indeed not the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Guilro's answer, generators allow you to write things like this:

```
controllerFunction(function*() {
    yield functionThatReturnsAThenable()
    yield anotherFunctionThatReturnsAThenable()
    return;
});
```

What the controller function does is call the generator, get whatever it returns from yield, chain a `next()` call to the `then()` of the returned value until the generator is `done`.

Something like this:

```
function controllerFunction(generator) {

    function run(runnableGenerator) {
        var result = runnableGenerator.next(); // or send(params)
        if (!result.done) {
            if (result.value.then) {
                result.value.then(function() {
                    run(runnableGenerator);
                });
            } else {
                run(runnableGenerator);
            }
        }
    }

    var runnableGenerator = generator();
    run(runnableGenerator);

}
```